# Save the Spring Security Context back to session for subsequent use

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My SpringBoot application is a packaged software application, to customize it I want to manipulate the authentication object when users first login, and I expect this object would be pushed back to the user's session for subsequent connection.

I managed to use an Around advice to intercept a REST endpoint that will be triggered when first login:

```
    @Around("execution( * com.myproject.CurrentUser.get(..)))"
    public ResponseEntity getCurrentUser(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Exception {

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(getNewAuthentication());

        ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextController.currentRequestAttributes())
            .getRequest().getSession().setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING.SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

        ResponseEntity response = (ResponseEntity) pjp.proceed();

        return response;

    }
```

The getNewAuthentication() method is confirmed OK, it returns a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken that includes additional authorities.

However in the subsequent REST calls when I check the Security Context object the authentication is still the original one.

May I know what would be the proper way to do this? I need to manipulate the authentication object at the very beginning and make sure the subsequent calls will make use of it.

Any idea?

Comment: What is spring security config? Do you want to add some dynamic authorities that is not present in database?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Yes I need to add some extra authorities. The original set is come from a LDAP server but I need some extra authorities that kept in the application local database.

Comment: I am looking at class `AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider` and it has a method `loadUserAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username, String password);`, I guess overriding that method to decorate the returned authorities.